# Can't understand the meaning of 'blamed exertion' in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

```
Doctors blamed exertion and said there was nothing to worry about.
```

I knew exertion means attempts or try.

But here what does that mean by 'blamed exertion'?

Comment: Your definition of *exertion* is wrong; that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: [Blame](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blame#Verb) - [exertion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exertion#Noun)

Answer (score 2):

In this instance *exertion* means vigorous activity or exercise.  The phrase 'blamed exertion' just means that the vigorous activity or exercise is what doctors blamed (perhaps for a fainting spell, for one example).